# Why can't I download files uploaded with PHP?

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, file-permissions, chmod

I have created a custom CMS with PHP and it uploads files to a directory with 777 permissions on it. When the files are uploaded they are given 600 with apache being the owner, therefore I can't download them through FTP as the main FTP user.

Anybody have any ideas? I have tried changing the permission but don't have rights due to the owner being apache.

Comment: Would you mind posting the pertinent upload code?

Comment: Try to [chmod](http://php.net/chmod) and/or [chown](http://php.net/chown) your files within the upload script.

Comment: You can change the permissions of the file on upload. Since the operation will be run as the apache user, it will be allowed.

Comment: You can set the sticky bit on the directory itself, which'll force the group permissions to apply to new files created in there. `chmod g+s /your/upload/dir`.

Comment: Thanks Marc B, this worked a treat. My VPS provider doesn't allow SSH so i was having real trouble setting the permissions. One little line of PHP has resolved my wasted saturday night.

Comment: Prefer 1777 for the temporary directory, that's the sticky bit, files will be owned by the creator of the file and users can only delete/rename their own files. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit

Answer (score 7):

You cant chmod the files, but 'apache' can: after uploading an moving the file,change the permissions in the same script. As it is run by apache, it is allowed to do so.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Answer (score 0):

For uploading files it is important to note that uploading files without explicitly setting permissions after is a bad practice.

I would take the link Nanne provided and begin to add that to your upload script. This will ensure that the files are given the appropriate permissions for each situation you will need them.